# how to change section order on hestia?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

hey guys ive been playing around with the wordpress theme "hestia" and ive come to a problem that I haven't been able to solve on my own:

the frontpage consists of a couple of sections, which you can only move around with the pro version, which I don't want to buy

I've look through the code of the theme but couldnt change the order, would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction

[image]

I want to move the "Team" section below the "Blog" section

## EDIT:

Thanks Tarun for your nice answer, sadly I get the following error when trying to add the code to functions.php:

> Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 18 of
>   file wp-content/themes/hestia-child/functions.php. Please fix and try
>   saving again.
>
> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   set_hestia_section_priority(), 1 passed in
>   wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 2 expected in
>   wp-content/themes/hestia-child/functions.php:18 Stack trace:
>   0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): set_hestia_section_priority(15) 
>   1 wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(15, Array)
>   2 wp-content/themes/hestia/inc/sections/hestia-about-section.php(68): 
> apply_filters('hestia_section_...', 15, 'hestia_about')
>   3 wp-content/themes/hestia/functions.php(694): include_once('w...')
>   4 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): hestia_include_features('')
>   5 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
>   6 wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>   7 wp-settings.php(434): do_action('after_setup_the...')
>   8 wp-config.php(89): require_once('/

Also, there doesn't seem to be a "hestia-team-section.php" file in my sections folder. (hestia-about-section etc. are there tho)

Comment: Where is the code you're trying to edit?  A picture of the top menu in the UI from the WP customizer is useless.  What sections are you trying to move around and to what position?

Comment: As I said in my post, I want to move the "Team" section below the "Blog" section. And Im not trying to edit any code, since I don't know where in the code that is.

Comment: "Below" is a relative position.  Do you want it one section down, two, three, offset, etc?  If you're not trying to edit code, then we really can't help you. Your question would be best asked in a support forum for the particular theme you're having trouble with, otherwise you're just taking a shot in the dark that someone is familiar with it.

Comment: I want to edit the code, since doing it via the UI is only included in the pro version. I just dont know WHERE the code I have to edit is. With "below" I mean right after Blog section. One section down.

Comment: Could give at least give link of the theme you are trying to edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the `plugin` in the file `./wp-content/plugins/themeisle-companion/obfx_modules/companion-legacy/inc/hestia/inc/sections/hestia-team-section.php`

There is below code

```
if ( function_exists( 'hestia_team' ) ) {
        $section_priority = apply_filters( 'hestia_section_priority', 60, 'hestia_team' );
        add_action( 'hestia_sections', 'hestia_team', absint( $section_priority ) );
        if ( function_exists( 'hestia_team_register_strings' ) ) {
                add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'hestia_team_register_strings', 11 );
        }
}
```

As you can see there is a `apply_filters`

```
$section_priority = apply_filters( 'hestia_section_priority', 60, 'hestia_team' );
```

Now you can use a child theme, I used `Child Theme Configurator` to generated the child theme. And then added the below code at the end of `functions.php`

```
if (!function_exists( 'set_hestia_section_priority') ) {
    function set_hestia_section_priority($current, $section_type) {
        if ($section_type == 'hestia_team')
            return 60;
        return $current;
    }
    add_filter('hestia_section_priority', 'set_hestia_section_priority');
}
```

[image: Custom Theme]

After that the result is as you expect

[image: Team after Blog]

Comment: thank you for your answer Tarun, sadly I get the above errors when trying to add the code

Comment: Please use the latest theme from https://themeisle.com/themes/hestia/, you may have a older version

Comment: I am sure I have the latest version

Comment: What is the wordpress version you have? I had that too as the latest `4.9.6`

Comment: I believe the `add_filter('hestia_section_priority', 'set_hestia_section_priority');` should be written as `add_filter('hestia_section_priority', 'set_hestia_section_priority', 10, 2);` (i.e. the important part is the `2` which would pass two arguments to the filter callback function.) That should fix the "Uncaught ArgumentCountError" error. @jogoe, *there doesn't seem to be a "hestia-team-section.php" file in my sections folder* - it's in the `wp-content/plugins` folder; [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6zse.jpg).

Comment: thanks @SallyCJ that was the error